# How many times does row from one df have values higher in a row of another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two df frames

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   '2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   '3': [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1': [53, 76, 77, 96, 58, 64],
                    '2': [42, 61, 65, 74, 45, 54],
                    '3': [36, 42, 24, 54, 10, 80],})
```

What I am looking for is a new column in `df` which states how many times that row has values from df2 in a row which are >= to each number.

[image]

Hope I’ve explained it well enough thanks

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': {0: 62, 1: 35, 2: 80, 3: 78, 4: 80, 5: 60, 6: 67, 7: 65, 8: 55, 9: 62}, 
                   '2': {0: 52, 1: 28, 2: 43, 3: 57, 4: 60, 5: 37, 6: 32, 7: 23, 8: 33, 9: 38}, 
                   '3': {0: 32, 1: 8, 2: 12, 3: 30, 4: 38, 5: 18, 6: 10, 7: 10, 8: 13, 9: 25}, 
                   '4': {0: 43, 1: 23, 2: 50, 3: 47, 4: 50, 5: 37, 6: 35, 7: 42, 8: 28, 9: 32}, 
                   '5': {0: 62, 1: 45, 2: 55, 3: 75, 4: 62, 5: 63, 6: 43, 7: 58, 8: 55, 9: 72}, 
                   '6': {0: 80, 1: 50, 2: 83, 3: 63, 4: 73, 5: 52, 6: 62, 7: 75, 8: 72, 9: 72}, 
                   '7': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 0}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 
                    '2': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 
                    '3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6:0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 
                    '4': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 
                    '5': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}, 
                    '6': {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60, 7: 70, 8: 80, 9: 90}, 
                    '7': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `apply`:

```
df["count"] = df.apply(lambda row: row.ge(df2).all(1).sum(), axis=1)

>>> df
   1   2   3   4   5   6  7  count
0  62  52  32  43  62  80  2      9
1  35  28   8  23  45  50  1      6
2  80  43  12  50  55  83  2      9
3  78  57  30  47  75  63  3      7
4  80  60  38  50  62  73  0      0
5  60  37  18  37  63  52  0      0
6  67  32  10  35  43  62  0      0
7  65  23  10  42  58  75  1      8
8  55  33  13  28  55  72  0      0
9  62  38  25  32  72  72  0      0
```

Comment: Okay so this worked on the test code but when applying to my actual code it returns zero every time and ideas why that may be thanks

Comment: It should work regardless. Provide a better sample where the error is reproducible.

Comment: I’m struggling to write it so that it fails. My dfs are from .read_excel but whenever i write a new data whitin python it works but not when reading from excel

Comment: `df.head(10).to_dict()` will give you a sample of your data from the excel.

Comment: The output of all zeros is correct. None of the rows in `df` is less than the rows in `df2`

Comment: So id like to know from the rows of df2 how many of df rows are => to df2

Comment: It’s strange so i started a new code added the df.heads in and your code works perfectly but as soon as i use it in the original code it just says 0

Comment: You mention >= but your example (expected output) was calculating <=. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry I’ve got the Same problem works in the new one but says 0 when used on the original code

Comment: Maybe 0 is the correct output for those rows. This code works as expected. Not sure what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `outer` `sub`

```
df['count'] = (np.subtract.outer(df2.to_numpy(),df.to_numpy())>=0).all((1,-1)).sum(0)
df
Out[307]: 
   1  2   3  count
0  0  0   0      6
1  0  0  10      6
2  0  0  20      5
3  0  0  30      4
4  0  0  40      3
5  0  0  50      2
```